# Jquery compare unix time and countdown

Tags: php, jquery, unix

I have a row in my table with a unix value, ex. 1471267007.
The thing is that I want my unix value to be in a countdown on my website.
 Every user having different unix value. And when the current unix time is same as the value in the row, the time left should be zero and the user should also be redirected to another page.

For example: 
**Time left: 2 min and 10 seconds**

Comment: What have you tried yet? Wouldnt it be easier to use a real time (see js date() )

Comment: @Jonasw Mostly checking out other people's scripts. I have no idea, mayne I should check it up! Thanks

Comment: @TimiFinschkenNikula did my answer help any?

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to this a few years ago. Its quite straight forward. You need to firstly get the current date in a unix value and compare this to the future date unix value. You can get the current date using the inbuilt javascript function Date.now().

so do something like:

```
//get current unix date
var currentDate = Date.now();
//get how many miliseconds are left from future date to current date
var timeRemaining = futureDate - currentDate;
// convert milliseconds to seconds
timeRemaining = timeReamining * 1000;
```

and then you just go from there, seperate the initial value into whatever values you need and then insert it onto the page using an asynchronous method such as `setInterval`set to run every second.

and then for your redirection just have another condition set under an asynchronous loop that goes something like:

```
if (timeRemaining =< 0) {
window.location.assign('yournewurl.com');
}
```

have a read up on setInterval if you have not used it before. You will get a lot more benefit from writing this yourself as a simple function than copying and pasting + if you have trouble you can put what you have written so far here and get some help :)